# Is there a correlation method available for large datasets which need iterative loading?

Tags: tensorflow, bigdata, correlation

For an ordinary DataFrame of modest size there are functions available to directly compute the correlation between two columns.

Suppose however, I have a very large dataset where I need to use tf.data API to process the rows iteratively.

Now of course I can manually write a function which computes the correlation for two columns by iterating though the data in batches (say of size 10000), computing covariances and variances on each batch and saving these in a list. I can then later write a function which builds the overall correlation using the list of covariances and variances. However, as this should be quite a common task, I wonder: Is there a simple builtin method, I can call on a tf.DataSet which avoids having to write all this boilerplate code?

Note: I want to have a solution which works on a single machine.